# Best Practice for testing with RunAs method

Tags: unit-test, bestpractice, test-setup

I noticed that when you create a user in a test class that the username must be unique in the real production environment. Most of my test classes are creating a user to then run the test method as.

The problem arises from the fact that you can create a test class, deploy it to production, and then have it break by someone else, coincidentally using that same username. Is there a best practice to avoid this besides trying to create long random usernames? Should we query for a random user in the org of that profile?

Comment: Why not use apextest@yourcompany.com or testuser@test.yourco.com

Comment: That would seem to increase the chance that an admin would create a test user with that name. Since we use communities there are a lot of test community users that have our company's domain.

Comment: String username = string.valueOfGmt(System.now());

Comment: I mock my user names starting with an underscore e.g. `_mockuser@foo.com`

Comment: Remember that usernames just need to be in a form of a email address it doesn't need to be a resolvable email address. So that unleashes a host of possibilities. I would keep the domain as yours because as you may have found out someone created a user with test@test.com as a username. By using your own domain will ensure that others will not take it. For example I would never create a user with @brezo.com, but you might.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With following combination to generate unique Username, there were no errors while using runAs with deployments:

```
public static User createTestUser(Id roleId, Id profID, String fName, String lName) {
    String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now())
        .replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
    Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
    String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;
    User tuser = new User(  firstname = fName,
                            lastName = lName,
                            email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                            Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
                            Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23),
                            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                            ProfileId = profId,
                            UserRoleId = roleId);
    return tuser;
}
```

I had referred to some blog or community answer for this resolving issue way back. Don't have link of original post, but noticed that its now mentioned in Salesforce documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000182266&language=en_US&type=1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.now() as username with some prefix like

```
String username = 'Test'+string.valueOfGmt(System.now());
```